# I was going to render the saved data into html table but found this error

Tags: django, django-templates

```
<tbody>
    {% for publication in publication_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{%publication.addpublication%}}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

views.py

```
def publicationlist(request):
    context = {'publication_list' : AddPublication.objects.all()}
    return render(request,"publication_list.html", context)
```

> TemplateSyntaxError at /addpublication/publicationlist/
>       Could not parse the remainder: '%publication.addpublication%' from '%publication.addpublication%'

Comment: You don't need the percent sign characters when you are rendering something - `{{ publication.addpublication }}`

Comment: thanks i got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
# You have to remove % in your td tag of html

<tbody>
    {% for publication in publication_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{publication.addpublication}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

For **tags** like `for`, `if`...:

```
{% for %}{% endfor %}
```

For **context variables**:

```
{{ my_context_variable }}
```